# Jenkins Pipeline Continiously

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

How to run Jenkins pipeline continuously?

The pipeline is started and once it's finished it runs again and so on

I tried */1 * * * * to run every minute but it's not waiting until the previous pipeline is finished but I need to wait until finished and only after it start running it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `disableConcurrentBuilds()` in your pipeline. This will prevent it to run till the previous ones complete.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trigger a new run of the pipeline as a last step (or a post step depending on a condition if you need to) of this same pipeline?

See the `build` step to do so: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job